# Reconcile counts from different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to reconcile counts from different tables in SQL Server. My table structure is something like:

`ID (Auto identity)    DivID    TableName    StagingCount   DWCount    DateCounted`

I can get the counts by using something like

```
select DivID, 'TableName', Count(*) from StagingTable Group BY DivID

UNION

SELECT DivID, 'TableName', Count(*) from DWTable Group By DivID
```

But the problem is that I get the counts on multiple rows.

```
DivID     TableName       Cnt    

1         Customer       2833    
1         CustomerDW     2833
```

What I like to get is:

```
DivID     TableName        StagingCount     DWCount
  1       Customer           2833            2833
  1       Product            1234            5678
  1       Address            8765            4321
```

How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: Are all the tables in the DW appended with `DW`? And are you sure this query runs? I'm pretty sure SQL Server should balk at the missing group by.

Comment: The difference between the staging tables and DW tables is that the Staging tables all have the word "staging" appended to them. For example, Products table on DW would have a corresponding ProductsStaging table in the database.

Comment: Correct. The group by is missing on there. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine your `union` via `subquery` to do the *conditional* aggregation

```
select DivID, 
       max(case when TableName = 'Customer' then cnt end) StagingCount,
       max(case when TableName = 'CustomerDW' then cnt end) DWCount,
       max(case when TableName = 'table3' then cnt end) table3count,
       . . .
from ((select DivID, TableName, Count(*) cnt 
       from StagingTable 
       Group BY DivID
       ) union 
       (select DivID, TableName, Count(*) 
        from DWTable 
        Group By DivID
       )
      )t
group DivID;
```

Comment: The DWCount column returns as Null for all the DivID's

Comment: @rvphx. . . That cause of invalid `TableNames` !! Provide valid table names in `max(case when TableName = 'Customer' then cnt end)`

Comment: Got that. I fixed it and it works fine. So, if I need to add more tables to the list, how would this change?

Comment: That would increase the number of output columns. Cant we do something like case when tablename in ?

Comment: @rvphx. . . I am actually confused between your table structure and your union query. I didn't find any link between them. So, my comment would be go in wrong place.

Comment: Pretty sure it involves a `GROUP BY REPLACE(...)` but I'm not 100% following along here either. I think OP has a list of tables in a table (hence the tablename column).